# Why exe file in System32 doesn't found in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I try to run "windows fax and scan" using VBA Excel, I use

```
Dim RetVal
RetVal = Shell("C:\Windows\System32\WFS.exe", 1)
```

the problem is the "file not found" error message always shows, I check some .exe files in "System32" directory, and the "file not found" error message always shows, I try another file extension and it works fine. So what do I have to do?

Comment: Did you manually check the folder and see if the file exists?

Comment: sure, it exists, I try another file extension in the same folder "system32" and the command works fine

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. It works as it should (Windows 11)... It looks something related to security, but the error is strange for such a case. Please, try the next way ( to open the exe file 'As Administrator': `CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\Windows\System32\WFS.exe", , , "runas", 1`. It may require to press `OK` at the UAC message...

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Dir("C:\Windows\System32\WFS.exe")` return in Immediate window?